# Delete strings from a list who do not contain certain words?

Tags: python, string, list

For example something like this (although it doesn't work):

```
list1 = ['hello, how are you?', 'well, who are you', 'what do you want']

desiredwords = ['hello', 'well']

list2 = [x for x in list1 if any(word in list1 for word in desiredwords) in x]

print list2

['hello, how are you?', 'well, who are you'] #Desired output
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `any` on the wrong generator expression. You want:

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if any(word in x for word in desiredwords)]
```

The difference here is that in your question you're evaluating whether or not any word in your desired words list is a member of `list1` (they're not), and then testing whether `False` (the output of your `any` call) is in the element of `list` that you're testing. This of course does not work.

My `any` version instead checks words in the desired words list against the element under consideration, using the output of `any` to filter the list.

Note that `in` on strings does substring matching - this approach will count "oilwell" as a matching "well". If you want that behavior, fine. If not, it gets harder.

Comment: Also you should make `desiredwords` a `set`, for performance, so that searching it is **O(1)** instead of **O(n)** with respect to the number of good words.

Comment: @aruisdante - I don't think that'll help as long as the OP is trying to do substring matching on the parent list. Or at least I'm not seeing how.

Comment: ah sorry I looked at it backwards. I assumed he was splitting the input phrase into words and seeing if the match. You're correct that as written it wouldn't help.

A regex would probably be most efficient for substring matching, but that's probably a bigger can of worms than the OP wants to deal with :p